# instafeedjs loads once only then images disappear! Ruby on Rails 4

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-4, instafeedjs

I am using instafeedjs to display images on a simple website I am building and it works great when the page is first loaded. If I navigate away from that page and then come back via navbar "home" button the images won't load/disappear, unless I refresh the page. Has anyone else had this issue and know of a fix? I think it has to do with cache but don't know the workaround. Also I am working in ruby on rails 4. Thanks!

Here is the code I have on the view page:

```
<section>
    <div class="container">
        <header>
            <div class="instafeed-content">
                <h2 class="text-center">Follow on Instagram</h2>
                <div class="row">
                    <div id="instafeed"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
        </header>
    </div>
</section>
```

Here is the code displaying the script inside my application.html.erb:

I have removed the info for userId, clientId, and accessToken but they are filled in properly in the code.

var userFeed = new Instafeed({
          get: 'user',
          userId: '...',
          target: 'instafeed',
          accessToken: '...',
          clientId: '...',
          resolution: 'low_resolution',
          limit: 4,
          sortBy: 'most-liked',
          template: '',
      });
      userFeed.run();

I hope this helps!

Comment: Can we see some of the code you've written so far?

Comment: Just updated with my code. Thanks!